# Twitter resizing tool for header image

Tags: image, twitter, resize, crop

I am trying to build the same tool (image can't be attached.. reput = 7) as twitter made to let users re-size / move their header image so they can save the part of the image they want.

> > the target image size is fixed.

Do you know if this is a well known plug in ?

I am having difficulties to build it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine one of these would suit your needs: http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php

Comment: Actually not. They are pretty different from the Twitter tool. Iviewer would be the nearest one https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki